# Best way to hide logo on smallest devices and show text instead?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hide

I know this might be a similar question but I couldn't find one that fit my situation.  I'm using Boostrap and have a logo that displays at top left, the problem is on small devices when the menu is toggled it looks funny so on smallest devices I would like to show text for the company name and not the logo.  What is the best way to do that?  Any help appreciated!

*At the moment I have both the text and the logo in, but you can see that without the text in there the logo would match...

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">             
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button> 

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        German Magic Farm

        <img src="img/german-magic-logo-sm-bars.png" width="110" height="133" alt="German Magic Farm Logo" longdesc="index.html">
    </a>
</div>
```

[You can see the test version of this site here](http://www.amystout.com/germanmagic/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[hidden classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)** to hide the logo on small device: `hidden-xs` or `hidden-sm` depending on what device you are targetting.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <span>German Magic Farm</span>
    <img class="hidden-xs" src="img/german-magic-logo-sm-bars.png" width="110" height="133" alt="German Magic Farm Logo" longdesc="index.html" >
 </a>
```

Or if you want to hide the text too on large devices you can do this:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <span class="hidden-md hidden-lg">German Magic Farm</span>
    <img class="hidden-xs" src="img/german-magic-logo-sm-bars.png" width="110" height="133" alt="German Magic Farm Logo" longdesc="index.html">
</a>
```

Comment: I'd have gone with `visible-xs` for the text span.

Comment: yh true, the thing too is: I don't if he always wants to have the text-span visible so what I did was just a suggestion but you are right on the visible-xs @isherwood

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your css file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .navbar-brand img {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is hiding the logo at devices from tablet and bellow, i think he was talking about mobile and this does not show any text.

Comment: He was talking about when the menu is "toggled" and that is at 768px. Also, the logo text is showing. (test it out)

Comment: No need for extra CSS when utility classes are already available.

Comment: To be clear I would like the logo to show, (and be up higher physically in the correct spot on page) on all devices except the smallest, then on the smallest I would like just the text so it looks good when menu is toggled.

Comment: Worked!  Can any of you make any more suggestions to this?